Cannot use System.IO.Ports in my C# .NET 8 console application
I have some experience in creating a C# application using .NET framework. However, I am stumped how to get this one solved.
Ok, spent the last hour trying to get the simplest of applications running  using C# and a .NET 8 console application.
My goal: read text from a serial USB connection from an ESP8266 serial monitor.
I have seen plenty of examples doing this:
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

SerialPort port = new SerialPort();

This utterly fails on my system. It seams that something is missing: the System.IO.Ports.
Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.

C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\Program.cs(7,1): error CS1069: The type name 'SerialPort' could not be found in the namespace 'System.IO.Ports'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Syst
em.IO.Ports, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly. [C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b.csproj]
C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\Program.cs(7,29): error CS1069: The type name 'SerialPort' could not be found in the namespace 'System.IO.Ports'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Sys
tem.IO.Ports, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly. [C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\Program.cs(7,1): error CS1069: The type name 'SerialPort' could not be found in the namespace 'System.IO.Ports'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Syst
em.IO.Ports, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly. [C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b.csproj]
C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\Program.cs(7,29): error CS1069: The type name 'SerialPort' could not be found in the namespace 'System.IO.Ports'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Sys
tem.IO.Ports, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly. [C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.50

Looking in the project explorer I see these:

I searched everywhere and there was the suggestion that I should install a NuGet package for this:

Results in:


C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b>dotnet add package System.IO.Ports --version 8.0.0
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\e2692\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb01oaz.tmp
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for code signing.
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for timestamping.
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'System.IO.Ports' into project 'C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b.csproj...
error: NU1101: Unable to find package System.IO.Ports. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
error: Package 'System.IO.Ports' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b.csproj'.

Some people suggest that the System.IO.Ports is not supported by .NET 8 (or any version at all). However, Microsoft has a manual page

Running on Windows 11. Tried Jetbrains Rider and Visual Studio 2022 Community edition.
Executing the dotnet --version in the project folder:
C:\sources\esp8266\USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b>dotnet --version
8.0.402

Outside:
C:\>dotnet --version
8.0.402

C:\>dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.425 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

More info on my project:

Solution properties:
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.11.35312.102
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "USBComPortReader6b", "USBComPortReader6b\USBComPortReader6b.csproj", "{92218195-33A1-48E3-B5DB-19B44769E322}"
EndProject
Global
        GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
                Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
                Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
                {92218195-33A1-48E3-B5DB-19B44769E322}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
                {92218195-33A1-48E3-B5DB-19B44769E322}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
                {92218195-33A1-48E3-B5DB-19B44769E322}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
                {92218195-33A1-48E3-B5DB-19B44769E322}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
                HideSolutionNode = FALSE
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
                SolutionGuid = {0298EA09-525B-42F7-954D-EC886703AEAC}
        EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal

The .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

To say I am frustrated is quite the understatement. I have dealt with my share of these platform related issues but I am completely at a loss how to solve this one.
ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

The answer is up there in the error message: System.IO.Ports is not cross-platform and net core/standard/5,6,7,8 is. I haven't tried it but I suspect it should work if you target net8.0-windows or add <RuntimeIdentifier>win</RuntimeIdentifier> to the project file.

The package supports Windows and Linux for sure, I've used it for a long time.  However, I only used v5.0.1 of System.IO.Ports, so maybe that is more compatible than the new one? I will do some testing.

I just compiled a much larger project using the 8.0 version of System.IO.Ports for a platform-independent target and it compiled just fine. I currently don't see where the difference would be.

That NU1101 error might also be a symptom of this.

@NPras this did the trick! Thanks for your tip. Who ever thought this source list is empty... I created an answer to document the steps I took to fix this based on your tip.

Thank you everybody for you support and tips!
So I added the package reference as @Basheer Jarrah suggested. That didn't help.
THen I followed the lead from @Npras about the NU1101 error (how to resolve "Unable to find package" nuget error). And indeed my package sources list was empty. After adding  the indicated source and restored the project the errors finally went away.
Source list (%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config) is now:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

After this I could compile without errors.
  dotnet restore

Conclusion: after a fresh install of Visual Studio Community Edition 2022 and fresh install of dotnet 6 of dotnet 8, there was no source list for the online packages. This must be fixed manually.

Add System.IO.Ports to .csproj file as the following:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

